# Derive 3D point array from multiple 2D projections of same point array

Tags: computational-complexity, problem-solving, projective-geometry

Let's assume that we have an array of $n$ 3D points, we don't know their coordinates (thus we have $3n$ indeterminate scalar values). We also have $m$ 2D projections with known coordinates (thus we have $2nm$ determinate values). Both 2D and 3D points are labelled, i.e. we know which 2D point in a certain projection corresponds to which 3D point. Projection matrices for each of $m$ projections are unknown, but if I understand 3D-to-2D projection correctly, the projection in this case could be defined by 3 Euler angles + 1 FOV (Field-of-View) angle. FOV is the same across all projections, which yields us another $3m + 1$ indeterminate values. Both 3D points and 2D projections are normalized (to eliminate translation and scaling) to some range, for example, 0 to 1.

Overall tally so far:

- $3n + 3m + 1$ scalar indeterminates
- $2nm$ determinate values
- Indeterminates are bound to determinates with $nm$ projection matrix equations

So, my questions are:

- Is it solvable at all, i.e is it possible to get 3D coordinates (+projection parameters) that would match all given 2D projections with a given amount of tolerance $\varepsilon$ (I strongly suspect it is, and, basically, it's the task that our brain is doing constantly analyzing two 2D images from both eyes, visualizing 3D image in mind)?
- Under which conditions it is solvable? (I suspect it's something like $3n + 3m + 1 < 2nm$, but I'm not sure)
- What's the approximate calculation complexity and best way to do it (I'm really lost here - would any generic multidimensional root finding algorithm do, or are there any complications / better way?)

Comment: Two projections, both doing lines in 3d space. line-line-intersection operation finds 3d point. Then it's just matter of pairing the points in projections.

Comment: Yep, I just forgot - we do know which point made which projection - I'll add that now, thanks. As for "line-line-intersection finds 2d point" - the problem here is that we don't know which projections were used exactly.

Comment: greycat: projection compresses some 3d points to same equivalence class. A line can be used to represent all those points. (if your projection is more complex, its just some kind of curve)

Comment: My projection is a perspective one, so it's not just a line, but a line + an angle (FOV). This yields additional free variable, but, technically, of course, it shouldn't matter with big enough $n$ and $m$.

Comment: You have labeled points so you know which projected points correspond to the same point in 3D, right?

Comment: That's right, I'll add this clarification to main question now.